# Using Try/Catch with naked functions

Tags: c++

Why using Try-Catch is not allowed with `naked` functions? And is there an alternative?

```
Error 2 error C2490: 'try' not allowed in function with 'naked' attribute
```

Comment: What do you mean by `naked`? And what's not allowed exactly?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ekezyy2(v=vs.80).aspx when I use try and catch statment with naked function I get compiling error telling that using Try with naked functions is not allowed

Comment: @HediNaily: Since it clearly says "Microsoft specific" you might want to add some more appropriate tags.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Non-standard but interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work to use exception handling over "naked" is that they functions don't have the standard prolog and epilog parts, which is necessary for "unwinding of the stack", which "catch" does. It says so [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d12973a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (limitations of naked functions).

You will need to find some other way to achieve what you want - either wrap your naked functions some way that "makes them dressed"[dressed = opposite of naked, not sure if that is the technical term] or don't use try-catch.

Answer (score 4):

> Structured Exception Handling and C++ Exception Handling constructs are not permitted because they must unwind across the stack frame.

(see [this link from the same site as above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d12973a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))